# How can we know about the HDFS threshold, do we have to check manually every time if using cloudera?

Tags: hadoop

How do we know about the HDFS threshold?

Do we need to check it manually every time if using cloudera?

Comment: what do you mean by threshold?

Comment: @SMA threshold is value used by the hdfs balancer to balance replication of the blocks under hdfs. It resolves the issue if blocks are under/over replicated. Suppose we set the threshold value to 5 then it means that each DataNode's disk usage must be (or will be adjusted to be) within 5% of the cluster's overall usage.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the threshold percentage for HDFS Balancer is 10 percent. You can change the default setting under hdfs-site.xml file

Find the property named

> dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct

If you want to workout with a specific threshold percentage in a particular time period then you can run the following command as a hdfs user

> hdfs balancer -threshold

Comment: okay . but how can we check if the threshold is reached to its limit? and do we need to ckeck that everytime manually or is there something we can set alert for that?

Comment: It's not like threshold has reached it's limit. Threshold is something you yourself specify so it doesn't really matter. I think you are not clear about the concept of threshold. I'd request you to read : http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_balancer.html  And there is as such no alert for this

Comment: Always a pleasure. Please accept the answer if I was able to solve your query

Comment: Cloudera Manager and Ambari can be setup to alert on a full HDFS usage @Tushar

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that is what I was asking. Thanks

Comment: @TusharBhoyar Accept the answer if it solves your query